# show text over lock screen

Tags: android, lockscreen

How can I show `TextView` and `EditView` over the lock screen?
I've tried this and I also add `TextView` in the layout but nothing has happened

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);



  }
```

then I tried this (in `Service`) and it didn't work too

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                        | PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setId('1');
    textView.setText("This is a demo");
    textView.setTextSize(15);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    mWindowManager.addView(textView, mLayoutParams);

 }
```

Help me please

Answer (score 1):

you need to do it like this:

```
wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                80, 80, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
                );
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        params.setTitle("text params");

        wm.addView(YourTextView, params);
```

Comment: Should I use onAttachedToWindow method or something like this?

Comment: you could just call that in a background service.  I mean how else are you going to show it ? if you want to show it when your activity is up that makes no sense to me. im guessing you want to show something when your app is in background or not present right ? you could use a Service as a service is a Context.  So i guess it depends on your intention.  you can call this code from anywhere that has a full context, because your attaching to the window manager.

Comment: I just want to do a simple lock app.User clicks the button and after that he always see my lock screen.But I have one problem:my addView doesn't work